# Using fold* to grow a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to solve the following problem in Haskell: given an integer return the list of its digits. The constraint is I have to only use one of the fold* functions (* = {r,l,1,l1}).

Without such constraint, the code is simple:

```
list_digits :: Int -> [Int]
list_digits 0 = []
list_digits n = list_digits r ++ [n-10*r] 
                where
                     r = div n 10
```

But how do I use fold* to, essentially grow a list of digits from an empty list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use `unfoldr`? Or something else also? All of the fold functions need some list (or `Foldable`) as input to fold over...

Comment: Alec, I was not familiar with unfold*. I think probably, that's the way to go (and what the problem requirement actually meant). Thank you.

Comment: You can get the digits backwards pretty easily with `list_digits = unfoldr (\i -> if i == 0 then Nothing else let (q,r) = quotRem i 10 in Just (r,q))`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment? It's pretty strange for the assignment to require you to use `foldr`, because this is a natural use for `unfoldr`, not `foldr`. `unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]` *builds* a list, whereas `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` *consumes* a list. An implementation of this function using `foldr` would be horribly contorted.

```
listDigits :: Int -> [Int]
listDigits = unfoldr digRem
    where digRem x
              | x <= 0 = Nothing
              | otherwise = Just (x `mod` 10, x `div` 10)
```

In the language of imperative programming, this is basically a `while` loop. Each iteration of the loop appends `` x `mod` 10 `` to the output list and passes `` x `div` 10 `` to the next iteration. In, say, Python, this'd be written as

```
def list_digits(x):
    output = []
    while x > 0:
        output.append(x % 10)
        x = x // 10
    return output
```

But `unfoldr` allows us to express the loop at a much higher level. `unfoldr` captures the pattern of "building a list one item at a time" and makes it explicit. You don't have to think through the sequential behaviour of the loop and realise that the list is being built one element at a time, as you do with the Python code; you just have to know what `unfoldr` does. Granted, programming with folds and unfolds takes a little getting used to, but it's worth it for the greater expressiveness.

If your assignment is marked by machine and it really does require you to type the word `foldr` into your program text, (you should ask your teacher why they did that and) you can play a sneaky trick with the following "`id[]`-as-`foldr`" function:

```
obfuscatedId = foldr (:) []
listDigits = obfuscatedId . unfoldr digRem
```

Answer (score 0):

Though `unfoldr` is probably what the assignment meant, you can write this using `foldr` if you use `foldr` as a *hylomorphism*, that is, building up one list while it tears another down.

```
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits n = snd $ foldr go (n, []) places where
  places = replicate num_digits ()
  num_digits | n > 0     = 1 + floor (logBase 10 $ fromIntegral n)
             | otherwise = 0
  go () (n, ds) = let (q,r) = n `quotRem` 10 in (q, r : ds)
```

Effectively, what we're doing here is using `foldr` as "map-with-state". We know ahead of time
how many digits we need to output (using log10) just not what those digits are, so we use
unit (`()`) values as stand-ins for those digits.

If your teacher's a stickler for just having a `foldr` at the top-level, you can get
away with making `go` partial:

```
digits' :: Int -> [Int]
digits' n = foldr go [n] places where
  places = replicate num_digits ()
  num_digits | n > 0     = floor (logBase 10 $ fromIntegral n)
             | otherwise = 0
  go () (n:ds) = let (q,r) = n `quotRem` 10 in (q:r:ds)
```

This has slightly different behaviour on non-positive numbers:

```
>>> digits 1234567890
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> digits' 1234567890
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> digits 0
[]
>>> digits' 0
[0]
>>> digits (negate 1234567890)
[]
>>> digits' (negate 1234567890)
[-1234567890]
```